# Gitlab "notifications" like github?

Tags: notifications, gitlab

In github there's a panel where one can look at one's notification like a mail inbox. Is there something similar for gitlab? I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on exactly what you're looking for.

For all mentions, assignments, and a few [other things](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/todos.html#actions-that-create-to-do-items), GitLab uses the ["To Do" list](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/todos.html).

If however, you mean you want a notification in the UI when there are new comments on any issue you're subscribed to, then there is [an epic on improving To Dos and notifications](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/1749). Most notable is the ability to at least [list all subscribed issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14972).